# Send SQL string through POST with httr package in R

Tags: r, post, web-scraping, httr

I'm trying to download a file from this website https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=289.
The form on that website, generates a POST link that submits a request to their server, to create a temporary file stored here https://transtats.bts.gov/ftproot/TranStatsData/.

As for the form data, I can see the following:

```
UserTableName: DB1BCoupon
DBShortName: 
RawDataTable: T_DB1B_COUPON
sqlstr: +SELECT+ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID%2CORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID%2CORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID%2CDEST_AIRPORT_ID%2CDEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID%2CDEST_CITY_MARKET_ID+FROM++T_DB1B_COUPON+WHERE+Quarter+%3D1+AND+YEAR%3D2017
varlist: ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID%2CORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID%2CORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID%2CDEST_AIRPORT_ID%2CDEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID%2CDEST_CITY_MARKET_ID
```

Based on the above, and with the httr package I've been trying the following:

```
library(httr)

web <- https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=289

POST(web, body = "+SELECT+ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID%2CORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID%2CORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID%2CDEST_AIRPORT_ID%2CDEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID%2CDEST_CITY_MARKET_ID+FROM++T_DB1B_COUPON+WHERE+Quarter+%3D1+AND+YEAR%3D2017", encode = "form")
```

Now I would expect to get a response header with the following info:

```
Location: https://transtats.bts.gov/ftproot/TranStatsData/847324776_T_DB1B_COUPON.zip
```

However, for some reason I can't seem to get this. I'm sure that the code for the POST is wrong but I'm not sure where or what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never (for an answer)?

That `POST` is super complex and the site does a redirect after processing it to another `GET` to grab the ZIP content.

[image]

Right-click on the `POST` line and choose "Copy as cURL". Do not modify the clipboard at all after that, then use [`curlconverter`](https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter) to turn it into an R function:

```
library(curlconverter)

straighten() %>% make_req() -> tmp # it automagically uses the clipboard contents
```

Hit "paste" on your OS and you'll get a longer version of this:

```
httr::POST(
  url = "https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DownLoad_Table.asp",
  httr::add_headers(
    Referer = "https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=289"
  ),
  body = list(
    UserTableName = "DB1BCoupon",
    DBShortName = "", 
    RawDataTable = "T_DB1B_COUPON",
    sqlstr = " SELECT ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID,ORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID,DEST_AIRPORT_ID,DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID FROM T_DB1B_COUPON WHERE Quarter=1 AND YEAR=2018",
    varlist = "ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID,ORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID,DEST_AIRPORT_ID,DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID",
    grouplist = "", suml = "",
    sumRegion = "", filter1 = "title=",
    filter2 = "title=", geo = "All\xa0",
    time = "Q+1", timename = "Quarter",
    GEOGRAPHY = "All", XYEAR = "2018",
    FREQUENCY = "1", 
    VarDesc = "ItinID", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "MktID", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "SeqNum", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Coupons", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Year", VarType = "Num", VarName = "ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID", 
    VarDesc = "OriginAirportID", VarType = "Num", VarName = "ORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID", 
    VarDesc = "OriginAirportSeqID", VarType = "Num", VarName = "ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID", 
    VarDesc = "OriginCityMarketID", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Quarter", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Origin", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OriginCountry", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OriginStateFips", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OriginState", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OriginStateName", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OriginWac", VarType = "Num", VarName = "DEST_AIRPORT_ID", 
    VarDesc = "DestAirportID", VarType = "Num", VarName = "DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID", 
    VarDesc = "DestAirportSeqID", VarType = "Num", VarName = "DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID", 
    VarDesc = "DestCityMarketID", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Dest", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "DestCountry", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "DestStateFips", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "DestState", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "DestStateName", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "DestWac", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Break", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "CouponType", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "TkCarrier", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OpCarrier", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "RPCarrier", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "Passengers", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "FareClass", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "Distance", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "DistanceGroup", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Gateway", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "ItinGeoType", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "CouponGeoType", VarType = "Num"
  ), 
  encode = "form",
  query = list(
    Table_ID = "289",
    Has_Group = "0", 
    Is_Zipped = "0"
  )
) -> res
```

(yep, *even longer* than that was)

The `sqlstr` parameter has the SQL query, and I'm not sure how much of that `POST` is "required" or not but it "worked for me"

`res` is definitely big and has binary zip'd data:

```
res
## Response [https://transtats.bts.gov/ftproot/TranStatsData/351117019_T_DB1B_COUPON.zip]
##   Date: 2018-10-14 02:18
##   Status: 200
##   Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed
##   Size: 14.6 MB
## <BINARY BODY>
```

We can save it to disk and make sure it's valid:

```
(save_to <- file.path("~/Data", basename(grep("\\.zip", unlist(res$all_headers), value=TRUE))))
## [1] "~/Data/351117019_T_DB1B_COUPON.zip"

writeBin(httr::content(res, as="raw"), save_to)

unzip(save_to, list = TRUE)
##                          Name    Length                Date
## 1 351117019_T_DB1B_COUPON.csv 378311108 2018-10-13 22:18:00
```