# Extract POST request from website not working anymore

Tags: r, asp.net, post, base64

This question follows an issue I had a few years ago which I posted here [Send SQL string through POST with httr package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798934/send-sql-string-through-post-with-httr-package-in-r).

The basic idea is to use R to download a zip file generated here https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIL&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4%20Pn44vr45.

When accessing the website above, we can select from a table, the variables we want, the year, and month (or all months), and press download.
Before, when I right-clicked on the POST line and choose "Copy as cURL", I would get a really nice set of code which I could translate into this:

```
httr::POST(
  url = "https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DownLoad_Table.asp",
  httr::add_headers(
    Referer = "https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=289"
  ),
  body = list(
    UserTableName = "DB1BCoupon",
    DBShortName = "", 
    RawDataTable = "T_DB1B_COUPON",
    sqlstr = " SELECT ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID,ORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID,DEST_AIRPORT_ID,DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID FROM T_DB1B_COUPON WHERE Quarter=1 AND YEAR=2018",
    varlist = "ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID,ORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID,DEST_AIRPORT_ID,DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID",
    grouplist = "", suml = "",
    sumRegion = "", filter1 = "title=",
    filter2 = "title=", geo = "All\xa0",
    time = "Q+1", timename = "Quarter",
    GEOGRAPHY = "All", XYEAR = "2018",
    FREQUENCY = "1", 
    VarDesc = "ItinID", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "MktID", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "SeqNum", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Coupons", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Year", VarType = "Num", VarName = "ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID", 
    VarDesc = "OriginAirportID", VarType = "Num", VarName = "ORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID", 
    VarDesc = "OriginAirportSeqID", VarType = "Num", VarName = "ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID", 
    VarDesc = "OriginCityMarketID", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Quarter", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Origin", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OriginCountry", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OriginStateFips", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OriginState", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OriginStateName", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OriginWac", VarType = "Num", VarName = "DEST_AIRPORT_ID", 
    VarDesc = "DestAirportID", VarType = "Num", VarName = "DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID", 
    VarDesc = "DestAirportSeqID", VarType = "Num", VarName = "DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID", 
    VarDesc = "DestCityMarketID", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Dest", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "DestCountry", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "DestStateFips", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "DestState", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "DestStateName", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "DestWac", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Break", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "CouponType", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "TkCarrier", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "OpCarrier", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "RPCarrier", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "Passengers", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "FareClass", VarType = "Char", 
    VarDesc = "Distance", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "DistanceGroup", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "Gateway", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "ItinGeoType", VarType = "Num", 
    VarDesc = "CouponGeoType", VarType = "Num"
  ), 
  encode = "form",
  query = list(
    Table_ID = "289",
    Has_Group = "0", 
    Is_Zipped = "0"
  )
) -> res
```

The code used to extract the cURL was this:

```
library(curlconverter)

straighten() %>% make_req() -> tmp
```

The new saved res, had binary data which I could easily use to download the zip file generated by the POST.

```
res
## Response [https://transtats.bts.gov/ftproot/TranStatsData/351117019_T_DB1B_COUPON.zip]
##   Date: 2018-10-14 02:18
##   Status: 200
##   Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed
##   Size: 14.6 MB
## <BINARY BODY>
```

However, when I do the same now it's a mess and I can't get anything from it.

```
httr::VERB(
  verb = "GET", url = "https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx",
  query = list(
    gnoyr_VQ = "FIL",
    QO_fu146_anzr = "Nv4+Pn44vr45' -X 'POST' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Origin: https://www.transtats.bts.gov' -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.279767402.1654087030; _ga_NQ5ZN114SB=GS1.1.1654601577.6.1.1654602173.0; _gat_gtag_UA_18660041_1=1; _gid=GA1.2.975702239.1654601578; f5avr1969959209aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_cspm_=DKBJFJCFEDEGJMPHAKDLLGKAOMIGFJJBLFKJJFLCOKMFKOPOIBLJNFBDAENMKNMNNBNCKLDMCJCFKOMIFAFAGDCBBEIKHALBFLPDDHNGGPNBOHCDHALHLHAFCPDCECCK; _gat=1; __utma=261918792.279767402.1654087030.1654149013.1654601578.6; __utmb=261918792.6.10.1654601578; __utmc=261918792; __utmz=261918792.1654087030.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _ga=GA1.3.279767402.1654087030; _gat_b=1; _gid=GA1.3.975702239.1654601578; has_js=1; QSI_SI_e8TSnTOxZxScWdT_intercept=true; QSI_HistorySession=https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=GEE&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4%20Pn44vr45~1653914765211|https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=GEE&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4+Pn44vr45~1653918802064|https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIL&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4%20Pn44vr45~1653926488227|https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIL&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4+Pn44vr45~1653933301130|https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FJE&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4Pn44vr45~1653943359984|https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIL&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4+Pn44vr45~1654090368888|https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIL&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4%20Pn44vr45~1654092812643|https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FLM&QO_fu146_anzr=b4vtv0+n0q+Qr56v0n6v10+f748rB~1654094623107|https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIL&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4%25Pn44vr45~1654102786829|https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIL&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4+Pn44vr45~1654601914519; f5avraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_session_=PBGOPMEEHCNFKKAPFNCACAKCCBFOPNPHICHCBEFGHCMKMLBFFNNFBOCOFLEKPFCNHNLDMANNOIAOFKNKGMJADPMKGDFMDGGEFHKCCGNOLACEFOLDEKIKCIOLAIIANEKM; ASPSESSIONIDQCQCSDSA=JPCOCLGDHAIJOKGLBBJNAKCN; _ga_TS9639848Y=GS1.1.1654095826.2.0.1654095826.0; ASPSESSIONIDQCSATBTA=PFAPIPGDONFFBLDGBBMOOAJO; ASP.NET_SessionId=wr043omrzfn1emifxmj1wadr; ASPSESSIONIDQCSASBTB=BMMLLHNBPOKMOHFPOHEOJOOB' -H 'Content-Length: 8825' -H 'Accept-Language: en-us' -H 'Host: www.transtats.bts.gov' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15' -H 'Referer: https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIL",
    QO_fu146_anzr = "Nv4+Pn44vr45' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data '__EVENTTARGET=chkAllVars",
    `__EVENTARGUMENT` = "",
    `__LASTFOCUS` = "", `__VIEWSTATE` = "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",
    `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` = "82CE8F70",
    `__EVENTVALIDATION` = "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",
    txtSearch = "", cboGeography = "All",
    cboYear = "2022", cboPeriod = "All",
    chkAllVars = "on", UNIQUE_CARRIER = "on",
    UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME = "on",
    ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID = "on",
    ORIGIN = "on", DEST_AIRPORT_ID = "on",
    DEST = "on", MONTH = "on"
  )
) -> res
```

In fact, when trying to run that res, it won't get any zip file anymore, and I suspect that it's due to this `__EVENTVALIDATION` and/or the `__VIEWSTATE`. I've been reading a lot about it, but I still can't figure out how to get around it so I can download the zip file from R.

Comment: Are you sure the API on the website hasn't changed?

Comment: @Limey There was never an API for this purpose. That's why I have to scrape it from the website like this. What I can't figure out is what changed from having a clear POST with the sqlstr to this weird POST with some coded stuff in it I don't really understand.

Comment: OK.  Generalise "API" to "any part of the website and its construction".  Generally, if something worked in the past and doesn't work now, something has changed.  Presumably everything at your end is the same (you'd tell us if it wasn't), so that means something at the other end has changed.  Even if the site *looks* identical, that doesn't mean its underlying structure is still the same.

Comment: @Limey. Indeed. Well that we know already, that something has changed. That's why I mentioned above that when I would copy the cURL from the same page element, it would give me something completely different. So something changed but I just can't figure out what and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by doing this.
I'm not sure why is it that I need a second request. One with GET and one with getURL. It seems that not having the GET request doesn't create a cookie for some reason. However, it works. But if someone could explain why, this would be amazing.

```
curl <- getCurlHandle()
    curlSetOpt(cookiejar = paste(tempdir(), "/", "cookies.txt", sep = ""),
               followlocation = TRUE, autoreferer = TRUE, curl = curl)

    message("Connecting to T100")
    html <- getURL("https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIM&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4%25Pn44vr45", curl = curl)
    temp <- GET("https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIM&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4%25Pn44vr45", curl = curl)
    message("Done")

    viewstate <- as.character(sub('.*id="__VIEWSTATE" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html))
    viewstategenerator <- as.character(sub('.*id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html))

    eventvalidation <- as.character(sub('.*id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html))

    message("Downloading file")

    httr::POST(
      config = progress(),
      url = "https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIM&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4+Pn44vr45",
      httr::add_headers(
        Referer = "https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FIM&QO_fu146_anzr=Nv4%25Pn44vr45"
      ),
      body = list(
        '__EVENTARGUMENT' = "",
        '__LASTFOCUS' = "",
        "__VIEWSTATE" = viewstate,
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' = viewstategenerator,
        '__EVENTVALIDATION' = eventvalidation,
        txtSearch = "",
        btnDownload = "Download",
        cboGeography = "All",
        cboYear = y,
        cboPeriod = "All",
        chkAllVars = "on",
        UNIQUE_CARRIER = "on",
        UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME = "on",
        ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID = "on",
        ORIGIN = "on",
        DEST_AIRPORT_ID = "on",
        DEST = "on",
        MONTH = "on"

      ),
      encode = "form", query = list(
        gnoyr_VQ = "FIM",
        QO_fu146_anzr = "Nv4+Pn44vr45"
      ),
      postData = list(
        text = paste("__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=", viewstate,
                     "&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=", viewstategenerator,
                     "&__EVENTVALIDATION=", eventvalidation,
                     "&txtSearch=&cboGeography=All&cboYear=",y,"&cboPeriod=All&btnDownload=Download&UNIQUE_CARRIER=on&UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME=on&ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID=on&ORIGIN=on&DEST_AIRPORT_ID=on&DEST=on&MONTH=on",
                     sep = "")
      )
    )
```